# import csv adding a header with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a csv without a header. And I'm trying to tweak my script so that a header is included during load.

In addition to including the header, can I define the field types?

```
import pandas, csv

from io import StringIO
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, header, data_iter):
   dbapi_conn = conn.connection
   with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
       s_buf = StringIO()
       writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
       writer.writerows(data_iter)
       s_buf.seek(0)
       s_buf.write(header + "\n" + old) #--> test creat header
       columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
       if table.schema:
           table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name, columns)
       else:
           table_name = table.name
       sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(table_name, columns)
       cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxxx:xxx/xxxxxx')

df = pandas.read_csv("xxx.csv")
df.to_sql('xxx', engine, schema='xxxx', method=psql_insert_copy)
```

the layout of the file I'm importing

```
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
```

header and types

```
cnpj varchar,
data date,
tipo char,
conta varchar,
value integer,
value2 interger,
value3 integer
```

Any ideas for implementation?

Comment: `pd.read_csv('xxx.csv', names=[list_of_col_names], dtype={dict_of_col_name: type})`

Comment: Please give us data sample and desired output to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pandas supports setting column names and data types in read_csv. You do have to use python types. The following should work.

```py
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

columns = {
    "cnpj": str,
    "data": date,
    "tipo": str,
    "conta": str,
    "value": int,
    "value2": int,
    "value3": int,
}

pd.read_csv("xxx.csv", columns=columns.keys(), dtype=columns)
```